# Unable to pass the object as parameter in constructor

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

```
class Projectile{
    constructor(position, velocity){
        this.position= position
        this.velocity = velocity
        this.radius = 30
    }

    draw(){
        c.beginPath()
        console.log(this.position.x + "  " + this.position.y)
        c.arc(500, 500, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
        c.fillStyle = "red"
        c.fill()
        c.closePath()
    }

    update(){
        this.draw()
        this.position.x += this.velocity.x
        this.position.y += this.velocity.y
    }
}
```

This is my class. I have made a constructor that takes two objects. I have used following line of code to make a new object of class. It should be an array of objects.

```
 const projectiles = [new Projectile({
    position: {
        x:300,
        y:300
    },
    velocity: {
        x:0,
        y:0
    }
})]
```

The problem is when I am printing the value of  `this.position.x` and `this.position.y` in console , it is printing undefined. I want the value that I have passed while creating the object.

Comment: did you mean `constructor({position, velocity}){`

Comment: `constructor(position, velocity)` takes 2 arguments, you are passing 1 object. Either modify the `constructor` or init as `new Projectile({x: 300, y: 300}, {x: 0, y:0})`

Answer (score 0):

```js
update(){
    console.log(this); // position: {position: {...}, velocity: {...}}, velocity: undefined, ...
    this.draw()
    this.position.x += this.velocity.x
    this.position.y += this.velocity.y
}
```

You are passing an argument only to the parameter `position`.

so you should change change like this

```js
 const projectiles = [new Projectile(
    // position
    {
        x:300,
        y:300
    },
    // velocity
    {
        x:0,
        y:0
    }
)]
```